# In JavaFX How to resize multiple images inside a parent node?

Tags: java, javafx

This is my code

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox OuterHBox = new HBox();

        Image image1 = new Image("file:resources/redseven.png", 200, 200, true, true);
        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image1);
        imageView1.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView1.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView1.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView1.fitWidthProperty().bind(OuterHBox.widthProperty());
        imageView1.fitHeightProperty().bind(OuterHBox.heightProperty());

        Image image2 = new Image("file:resources/redseven.png", 200, 200, true, true);
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image2);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView2.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView2.fitWidthProperty().bind(OuterHBox.widthProperty());
        imageView2.fitHeightProperty().bind(OuterHBox.heightProperty());

        OuterHBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView1, imageView2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(OuterHBox, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void loadFontStuff() {
        Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("TRON.TTF").toExternalForm(), 10);
        System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("TRON.TTF"));

    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

What I want is when I make the window smaller by reducing it's width or reducing it's height, both the images inside should resize and be visible.

When I reduce the height, I see both images resizing to fit the screen.
[image]

But when I reduce the width, both images don't resize. Second image disappears out of view.

[[image: Second image disappearing[3]]

When I reach the first image, it resizes itself.

[image: first image resizes correctly]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting width to image when outerbox's width get changed.
You can add a width change listener to the outerbox and distribute the updated width to the images equally. You need to remove fitWidthProperty because each image will use complete outerbox width.
Please update your code like this:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox OuterHBox = new HBox();

        Image image1 = new Image("file:resources/redseven.png", 200, 200, true, true);
        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image1);
        imageView1.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView1.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView1.setPreserveRatio(true);
        // imageView1.fitWidthProperty().bind(OuterHBox.widthProperty());
        imageView1.fitHeightProperty().bind(OuterHBox.heightProperty());

        Image image2 = new Image("file:resources/redseven.png", 200, 200, true, true);
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image2);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView2.setPreserveRatio(true);
        // imageView1.fitWidthProperty().bind(OuterHBox.widthProperty());
        imageView2.fitHeightProperty().bind(OuterHBox.heightProperty());
        // Updated Code============
        OuterHBox.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            imageView1.setFitWidth(newValue.doubleValue() / 2);
            imageView2.setFitWidth(newValue.doubleValue() / 2);
        });
        OuterHBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView1, imageView2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(OuterHBox, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void loadFontStuff() {
        Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("TRON.TTF").toExternalForm(), 10);
        System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("TRON.TTF"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is with the combination of `setPreserveRatio(true);` and the binding. When you trying to increase the image height, because it has to keep its dimension ratio ( cause of `setPreserveRatio(true);` ), the ImageView will scale the width as well, forcing the HBox to increase its size and when it finally reaches more than the actual stage width it will make a part of the images to be hidden. You could set the `setPreserveRatio` to **`false`** unfortunately in that case the first Image will always try to get all the available space of the HBox and you will not be able to see the second Image.

In my opinion, I believe it's for the best to manually set the `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` of each ImageView by calculating the available space inside your pane. Here is an example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private ArrayList<ImageView> allImages = null;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox mainPane = new HBox();

        try {
            allImages = createImages(10, "icon.png");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (allImages == null || allImages.isEmpty()) {
            Platform.exit();
        }

        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(allImages);

        mainPane.widthProperty().addListener(e -> {
            double fitWidth = mainPane.widthProperty().get() / allImages.size();
            for (ImageView iv : allImages) {
                iv.setFitWidth(fitWidth);
            }
        });

        mainPane.heightProperty().addListener(e -> {
            double fitHeight = mainPane.heightProperty().get();
            for (ImageView iv : allImages) {
                iv.setFitHeight(fitHeight);
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ArrayList<ImageView> createImages(int count, String string) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<ImageView> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("icon.png").toURI().toURL().toString());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            list.add(imageView);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I am loading ten Images and display them in single row. Each time the user resize the Stage it will trigger an event which mainPane (your HBox) handles. Then finds out how many Images there are and how much space we have to fill, all you have to do then is to set the appropriate size for each ImageView and your are done. The Example above is working fine if you set the `setPreserveRatio` to **false** too.